# Select a specific index row in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I have an index and I need to find out what is the row in a table with that index, in SQLite.
Example:

Index = 1

Table:

```
ID   -    Name
aa1      John
aa2      Mark   <-- I need this row
aa3      Lucy
aa4      Jim
```

Which is the correct SELECT that I can use to solve my problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Typically to get a specific row you can always request them by `rowid`, e.g.

```
SELECT name FROM UnknownTable WHERE rowid = 1;
```

However, there are some atypical situations that preclude this.  You'll really want to read up on [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)s to ensure that your table is going to behave as you want.

Answer (score -4):

Select Id
,Name
From Tracks
WHERE Id = 'aa2';

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. They want to select the row by its _index_, **not** by its `ID`. See the accepted answer for how they solved it.

Comment: Hey Prajwal, thanks for your efforts. It can be tough answering questions on StackOverflow but don’t give up, your first attempt was better than most. 

Formatting really helps and like this question, the devil is in the detail.—It’s always worth a re-read of the question before posting. 

Formating cheatsheet: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help